# Java 8 stream for Map <String, Set<String>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map< Integer, Set < Integer > >. I would like to convert it to a list of Integers based on some modification done by a custom method.

Right now I am using two for loops and I wanted to know if there's a better way to do it using java streams

Here's my existing code:

```
public myMethod(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> myMap, String a, int b) {
List<Integer> myIntegerList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i: myMap.keySet()) {
        for ( int j: myMap.get(i)) {
            myIntegerList.add(myCustomMethod(i, j, a.concat(b));
        }
    }
}

public Integer myCustomMethod(int x, int y, String result) {
...
...
...

return Integer;
}
```

I wanted to know if we could iterate through the set of integers using java stream() ?

Comment: Your existing code doesn’t compile. The return type is missing (should be `void`) and `a.concat()` cannot be applied to an `int` argument (perhaps concatenation using `a + b` was intended, I don’t know). Also I assume the next method should have been declared `public Integer myCustomMethod(int x, int y, String result)`. And an `Integer` instance should have been given after `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public void myMethod(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> myMap, String a, String b) {
        List<Integer> myIntegerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i: myMap.keySet()) 
            myIntegerList.addAll(myMap.get(i).stream().map(j -> myCustomMethod(i, j, a.concat(b))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

I change variable "b" to String because concat need String (but if you need *int* , you can use method `Integer.toString(b)`

Comment: It’s generally considered better style to iterate through the map’s entry set (as, for example, chrisrhyno2003’s answer does) than to iterate through the key set and then use `get()` to get the value for each key. You can obciously do that with a loop too (`for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry : myMap.entrySet())`).

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Integer> myIntegerList = myMap.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(myEntry ->
                myEntry.getValue().stream()
                    .map(setEntry -> myCustomMethod(myEntry.getKey(), setEntry, a + b)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```