# Map<String, Set<T> > to List in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So I have this class :

```
 class User {
    public String name;
    public Integer age;

    public User(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

And then this `Map`:

```
 Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("User", Set.of(18, 19, 20, 21));
```

I want to obtain a list of 4 users here:

1. name : "John" , age : 18
2. name : "John" , age : 19
3. ....
4. ....

Any ideas how can I do it with `streams` in Java 8 ?

Comment: shouldn't the question just be tagged with `java-stream` rather than `java-9`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 stream for Map <String, Set<String>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640114/java-8-stream-for-map-string-setstring) Not generalising it but seems like the answer here would have solved the same anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<User> users = map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(x -> new User(e.getKey(), x)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`Set.of` is java-9 btw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 stream for Map <String, Set<String>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640114/java-8-stream-for-map-string-setstring) ? Not generalizing it but seems like the answer here would have solved the same anyway.